# Can you prevent SQL Server Audits from creating a new file for each session?

Tags: sql-server, audit

I've chosen my sql audit destination to be a file, and it appears to create a new file after each new session.  For example, a new audit file is created each time the computer restarts.  I have a few questions:

1. Is this normal/expected?
2. Is there a way to put audits in only one file?  Maybe this is silly if the multiple files serves a purpose...

Thanks in advance!

[SQLAUDIT Files generated for each new session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDVH8.png)